Calling "history -s" prevents function call from being added to history
Problem
I want to append an item to history from a function, but don't want to run it.
So from inside the function I call history -s.
This works, but causes the function call itself to not be added to the history file.
Example:
$ test123() { history -s 'echo "here"'; }
$ test123 "args"
$ cat "$HISTFILE"
...
echo "here"

If I remove history -s from my function, and call the function again, the function call is correctly added to the History File:
$ test123() { echo "nothing"; }
$ test123 "args"
$ cat "$HISTFILE"
...
test123 "args"

What I have Tried:
I have tried adding to my function history -n and history -w to add history file to current history lines and to write to the history file. But this doesn't solve the problem.
In my ~/.bashrc to preserve history between terminals and append automatically to history file after a command is run I have:
shopt -s histappend
export PROMPT_COMMAND='history -n; history -a'

This shouldn't be causing my problem, but I still tried changing and removing these values and it is still the same result.


This works, but causes the function call itself to not be added to the history file.

Yes and no.  Per the bash man page, the history -s command has this effect:

Store the args in the history list as a single entry. The last command in the history list is removed before the args are added.

(Emphasis added.)
If you typed the history -s command into an interactive shell then it would itself be the command that gets removed.  That may be why this particular detail is not documented in the HTML Bash Reference Manual.  You need to bear in mind, however, that the Bash history is of commands typed, not commands executed.  In particular, when you execute a shell function, the commands in its body are not logged into history.  That's why in your case, the history -s command in your function's body removes the function-call command, not itself.
If you need to synthesize a history entry from inside a function, then your best alternative might be to write it to a file, then read it into the history list with history -r.  For example:
test123() {
  tmpfile=$(mktemp)
  printf %s\\n 'echo "here"' >"$tmpfile"
  history -r "$tmpfile"
  rm "$tmpfile"
}

That would be cleaner if a process substitution could be used in place of a physical temp file, but that did not work for me.  I don't know why.
